# Vue common component communicate with different parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a requestion, how about vue.js's common component's best practice when communicating with different parent component.

for example, in my scenario, a basic modal component, trigger a 'close' method, but it has two different parent component

I find two solutions:

1. parent need pass an additional prop, and then baisc component just
   trigger event which event's name is the prop value, so the listener
   parent component attched on could be called
2. in basic modal just use this.$parent to visit parent component methods, or this.$parent.trigger('xxx'), and then parent knows what to do

But, both above I think not very good, the first may need pass an additional prop, this let others who write a third, a forth parent component use the basic component not very handy. And the second may be felt more hard coded.

So, is there is better solution in this case?

Comment: I would go for second option, anyway you said `a basic modal component, trigger a 'close' method`, should a close method held by modal component itself not by parent? or you probably want to trigger closing other element? Show your code so I can clearly figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.$dispatch('eventName', data)` (for Vue 2.x, use `this.$emit('eventName', data)`), to trigger an event to any parent, grandparent and further up the chain (you can use `this.$broadcast('eventName', data)` to trigger events down the chain in Vue < 2.x).

If the parent has an event called 'eventName' then it will fire this event.

If you have multiple parents, you can give them each a different event and from the child fire this specific event via dispatch. You can also give each parent the same event and pass a data prop that specifies what the parent should do. Third option is to refer to the specific parent:

```
var parent = new Vue({ el: '#parent' })
// access child component instance
parent.$refs.eventName()
```

Each option has pros and cons. The best solution depends on the context. But I think that the best solution in general is option 1. Then you don't need an additional data parameter. Option 3 is not loosely coupled.

For more info: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html

Comment: In Vue 2.0+ use `this.$emit('eventName', data)`  to trigger parent event not `$dispatch`